# Inserting Russian characters in cassandra table. CQL Shell not set to cp65001

Tags: windows, cassandra, datastax

I use the DataStax distribution of Cassandra (v. 3.9.0) in Windows10.

I run both cassandra.bat and cqlsh.bat in command prompt for whom I write:

```
C:\DataStax\...\bin>chcp 65001
```

I open the Cassandra CQL Shell, but still I am getting the warning "console codepage must be set to cp65001 to support utf-8 encoding on Windows platforms"

I create a table

```
CREATE TABLE emp(
emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name varchar, emp_city varchar, emp_sal varint, emp_phone varint);
```

I insert some registers:

```
INSERT INTO emp (emp_id, emp_name, emp_city,
   emp_phone, emp_sal) VALUES(1,'ram', 'Hyderabad', 9848022338, 50000)
USING TTL 0;
```

Up to this point it goes well. But when I try to perform an insert containing Russian characters:

```
INSERT INTO emp (emp_id, emp_name, emp_city,
   emp_phone, emp_sal) VALUES(9, 'Надежда', 'Mосква', 9841027331, 105000)
   USING TTL 0;
```

When I perform SELECT * FROM emp; I get:

```
  9 |    M????? |  ??????? | 9841027331 |  105000
```

Also, if I do it from the command prompt where I executed: cqlsh.bat --encoding utf-8, I cannot even execute the code, it doesn't recognize the colon (;). This is what happens:

```
INSERT INTO emp (emp_id, emp_name, emp_city,
            ...    emp_phone, emp_sal) VALUES(9, 'Надежда', 'Mосква', 
9841027331, 105000)
   USING TTL 0;
            ...
            ...
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you try to change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8?

Comment: Thank you. I couln't solve my problem using the Cassandra shell but I could do it using the client for Python. 

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
at the beggining of the .py and then:

session.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO emp (emp_id, emp_name, emp_city, emp_phone, emp_sal)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    USING TTL 0
    """,
    (9, u'Надежда', u'Mосква', 9841027331, 105000)
)